# Wordpress single item dynamic content

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress offers great customization for posts, pages and custom post types, but  the only thing I cant figure out is how to make a single item.

Let me give you an example: I have one image on my front page and I want it to be dynamic or maybe I have a telephone in the footer. How can I make them dynamically editable without hardcoding page/post IDs in the theme.

Is this possible without plugins?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  Take a look at custom fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. However for your use cases WordPress has the perfect built-in mechanism which is exactly meant for things like this. **Widgets**.

Most probably your Theme already has all dynamic areas which you may need registered. Go to

> Design -> Widgets

and populate them.

This is how you do it with your own code.

Register a dynamic sidebar within your Theme:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_sidebars' );

function my_sidebars() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Foo', 'theme-slug' ),
        'id' => 'bar',
        'description' => __( 'I am in area XYZ.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
```

Put this code where you want it to be:

```
<div id="my_dynamic_content">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'my-dynamic-content' ); ?>
</div>
```

For 99 % of use cases the existing text widgets are enough. You can also install a Plugin for WYSIWYG widget or code your own widgets. Whatever you need is possible.

More information here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets

Comment: Hm, I've always thought widgets are for the sidebar. Is it a good practice to use it elsewhere?

Comment: Its called "dynamic_sidebar" for historic reasons this is long long ago from WordPress 2.2. Almost every theme is using Widgets for the header, the footer and areas which you always see. But it is also not bad practice to use them for special pages if you describe the purpose of the area well. Look at all the Page Builders: They are even using widgets for post / page contents.  Also have a look at the "description" property of register_sidebar: Possible value: "For dynamic contents on the frontpage ...".

Comment: If you have a dynamic content which is different for every post / page or custom post type THEN you simply should use custom fields and/or shortcodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shortcodes (custom or plugin):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortbus/
or
php function to /wp-content/your-theme/function.php

Comment: I'm talking globally, for the theme, not to use in single posts/pages. Like - edit it somewhere and its set for the whole website. Fof items that display on every page for example

Comment: you can create shortcode "myphone", and use it on all pages: [sb name=”myphone”]. And change it on settings page for all pages.